# Programmatically check if a Google App can access your location (not GPS)

Tags: java, android

Google Apps can access your location, but this functionality may be either enabled or disabled:

[image]

How can I programmatically check if a Google App can access your location?
I am use this code but nothing is changing.

```
 boolean servicesOK() {
  int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
        .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    return true;
} else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
            this, AtlastActivity.GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
    dialog.show();
} else {

}
```